# Rails engines extending functionality

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-engines

I have an engine which defines some models and controllers. I want to be able to extend functionality of some models/controllers in my application (eg. adding methods) without loosing the original model/controller functionality from engine. Everywhere I read that you simply need to define controller with the same name in your application and Rails will automatically merge them, however it doesn't work for me and controller in engine is simply ignored (I don't think it's even loaded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just if anyone else runs into same issue some time in the future, this is the code I wrote that fixed my problem:

```
module ActiveSupport::Dependencies
  alias_method :require_or_load_without_multiple, :require_or_load
  def require_or_load(file_name, const_path = nil)
    if file_name.starts_with?(RAILS_ROOT + '/app')
      relative_name = file_name.gsub(RAILS_ROOT, '')
      @engine_paths ||= Rails::Initializer.new(Rails.configuration).plugin_loader.engines.collect {|plugin| plugin.directory }
      @engine_paths.each do |path|
        engine_file = File.join(path, relative_name)
        require_or_load_without_multiple(engine_file, const_path) if File.file?(engine_file)
      end
    end
    require_or_load_without_multiple(file_name, const_path)
  end
end
```

This will automatically require files from engine before requiring from application if file path starts with 'app'.

Comment: This solution doen's work for Rails 3, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045068/extending-controllers-of-a-rails-3-engine-in-the-main-app

Comment: I created a gem from this answer about a year ago but forgot to post it here. It works well for us: https://github.com/EPI-USE-Labs/activesupport-decorators

Answer (score 20):

```
require MyEngine::Engine.root.join('app', 'models', 'my_engine', 'my_model')
```

before the model class definition in your application.

Answer (score 8):

You can add these lines to you engine's module file in the lib root directory:

```
def self.root
  File.expand_path(File.dirname(File.dirname(__FILE__)))
end

def self.models_dir
  "#{root}/app/models"
end

def self.controllers_dir
  "#{root}/app/controllers"
end
```

Then you have the ability in the main application (the app making use of the engine) to require the necessary files from the engine. This is nice because you maintain Rails Engines default functionality and also have an easy tool for making use of normal ruby inheritance, without the need for patching.

EX:

```
#ENGINE Model -

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def testing_engine
    puts "Engine Method"  
  end
end

#MAIN APP Model -

require "#{MyEngine.models_dir}/user"
class User
  def testing_main_app
    puts "Main App Method"  
  end
end

#From the Main apps console

user = User.new

puts user.testing_engine #=>  "Engine Method"

puts user.tesing_main_app #=> "Main App Method"
```

Comment: what is the benefit of doing it this way compared to the MAIN APP Model inheriting from the ENGINE model?

Comment: If a model.rb file is present in the MAIN APP and the ENGINE APP but the ENGINE APP .rb is not required in the MAIN APP .rb, Rails ignores the ENGINE APP .rb. ENGINE to MAIN app does not follow normal ruby inheritance, at least when I wrote this answer.

Comment: I like this solution! My question is: what if the User in the engine in namespaced?

Answer (score 1):

That is true. The controller that is found first will be used.

So to make it work you might have two options:

- create a local copy of the controller, and modify the method you need
- if you have control over the plugin, you could create a Module containing the code and [include](http://macournoyer.wordpress.com/2007/07/06/extending-your-include-knowledge-of-ruby/) the code in both controllers, only overriding the method in your local controller. 
  According to me, since there is no multiple inheritance, that is the only way.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the load order of the engine to avoid the require on each of your models.

In config/application.rb add this line:

```
module MyApp
  class Application
    config.railties_order = [MyEngine::Engine, :main_app, :all]
  end
end
```

This will ensure that the models from MyEngine are loaded before MyApp

Comment: As far as I'm aware, Rails autoloading finds the first definition (the engine model in your case) and uses it, it doesn't go through the other paths to load possible other definitions of the same model.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used Engines before but can't you define a new controller that inherits from the controller provided by the engine

Comment: Not if they have the same name.

Comment: What about if they're in a seperate Namespace