# how to override rails 3 engine models and controllers in the main application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

I want to be able to override models and controllers of my rails 3 engine in the base app.

Inspecting $LOAD_PATH, I found engine's 'app/{models,controllers}' there, but I can't explicitly require engine's model or controller file: require 'engine_name/model_name' fails with "no such file" (tried with both namespaced(app/controllers/enginename/*) and plain engine).

So, what's the best way to extend engine's models/controllers in rails 3 without copying them to base app?

---

Basically, it's a load order problem. So, if I explicitly require model from engine, everything's ok, but I hope there is a better way.

Comment: what do you mean by "users to be able to override models and controllers?

Comment: I mean other developers, that use my engine. Users of engine)

Comment: Have you tried the following solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964050/rails-engines-extending-functionality/2990539#2990539

Comment: ... or this one for Rails 3 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045068/extending-controllers-of-a-rails-3-engine-in-the-main-app

Comment: by explicitly require, do you mean something like this? ````require Qe::Engine.root.join('app', 'controllers', 'qe', 'answer_sheets_controller')````, where ````qe```` is the Engine's isolated namespace?

Answer (score 6):

So I actually went back and wrote the documentation. The answer is to Open Class the Controller and Model classes using either,

- Class#eval_class
- ActiveSupport::Concern

More details here,
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#overriding-models-and-controllers

(edited. Changed from "edgeguides" subdomain to "guides" subdomain)