# Reopen models and controllers from Engine in Rails 3.x app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I want to extend the models and controllers from Engine by reopening them in the Rails app. The problem is they are not loaded when the app starts. I know there are some solutions for this like [Rails engines extending functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964050/rails-engines-extending-functionality/2990539) and [how to override rails 3 engine models and controllers in the main application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4009553/how-to-override-rails-3-engine-models-and-controllers-in-the-main-application), but I suspect this is due to the loading sequence of rails, and there should be some neat solution.

Then I come across with this solution:

```
config.railties_order = [Blog::Engine, :main_app, :all]
```

However, models and controllers in Engine are loaded, but not the ones in rails.
Just wondering if anyone made this work before?

Comment: Here a clean solution [using concerns][1].

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11675951/testing-model-extensions-for-engines

Answer (score 0):

You can reopen the controller classes by having the main Rails application controllers inherit from a Rails Engine. This did not require the `config.railties_order` in order to get the controllers working,

```
#/app/controllers/answer_sheets_controller.rb
require YourCustomEngine::Engine.root.join('app', 'controllers', 'your_custom_engine', 'answer_sheets_controller')

class AnswerSheetsController < YourCustomEngine::AnswerSheetsController
```

From some reason, this strategy is not working for the models.

Comment: That's sad. But I have come up with another solution, see below. Not pretty but tidy (don't know how to put codes in the comments)

Comment: @TinmanChan - here's another solution. https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/rubyonrails-core/jy2dQ0BQhnM

Answer (score 0):

My Solution:

```
# === in engine
class EngineNameSpace::Blog
  # logic goes here
end

class Blog < EngineNameSpace::Blog
  # no codes should go here
end

# === in app
# If I need to extend the Blog class, I will code as below instead of reopenning the class
class Blog < EngineNameSpace::Blog
  # do something
end
```

Explain:

Rails blocks the engine classes from loading if they are the same file name/path as something in the parent app., see http://www.cowboycoded.com/2011/02/06/making-the-case-for-rails-3-engines/