# How to get the list of all engines in Rails 3 app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-plugins, rails-engines

According to [Rails engines extending functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964050/rails-engines-extending-functionality) in Rails 2.x one could do

```
Rails::Initializer.new(Rails.configuration).plugin_loader.engines
```

This code is not working in Rails 3

```
ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `new' for Rails::Initializer:Module):
  config/application.rb:12:in `require_or_load'
```

What do I need to do in Rails 3 to get such list of engines?

This is needed for [Extending controllers of a Rails 3 Engine in the main app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5045068/extending-controllers-of-a-rails-engine-in-the-main-app)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of 5/10/2011 and Rails 3.1 beta, it's now

```
Rails::Application::Railties.engines
```

Answer (score 17):

This has changed with Rails 4.1.  The accepted answer is deprecated and the new way to get the installed Engines for a Rails application is now:

```
::Rails::Engine.subclasses.map(&:instance)
```

[Here's a reference to the commit in github](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/4a2a504f40a8b6eec88e6aafefcf8e579a24e1c9#diff-7d0a784885a7ba0f99b77cb306dba31b) making the change (and also showing how it was implemented after initial deprecation...)

If you need to use the previous solution from Rails 4.1:

```
module Rails
    class Engine
        class Railties
            def self.engines
                @engines ||= Rails::Engine.subclasses.map(&:instance)
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Yes - the question was for a Rails 3 app, but it is still misleading to stumble upon this answer without the latest and greatest having a presence.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
Rails::Application.railties.engines
```

Comment: great, it works! Could you also advise me how I can get directory of the engine?

Comment: Ok, I've found it: `Rails::Application.railties.engines.first.config.root`