# Monkeypatch across Engines in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, metaprogramming, rails-engines, monkeypatching

First of all: Yes, monkey patching is bad, I'm feeling like a sinner already. But in this case I haven't found another solution.

Situation:

Engine 1 (Alchemy-CMS): Provides a page model that contains several elements.

Engine 2 (my Alchemy-Contentable): Should provide a way to bind these elements to any resource (=model) you like.

Purpose is to give the resource cms-capabilities like Alchemy has, that means adding elements like headings, paragraphs, pictures, videos...

On the "page-layer" everything is fine. I created a mixin for a model that identifies itself as contentable towards the element.

I want to stay as close as possible to alchemy and therefore inheriting from element is not an option (new database-table, new associated models...). 
So monkey patching seems adequate here (still hacky, but I'm fine with it this time I guess).

Problem:

How do I successfully monkey-patch one engine's classes from another engine?
When I try to reopen classes as usual it complains not to find the constant. Probably this is due to lazy loading of classes.

What works is:

```
config.after_initialize do
  Alchemy::Admin::ElementsController.send(:include, AlchemyContentable::ElementsControllerMixin)
  Alchemy::Admin::ElementsController.send(:before_filter, :load_contentable_to_page, :only => [:index, :new, :create])
end
```

but this seems to be error prone, especially when accessing a newly defined message from a mixin (like Alchemy::Element.my_new_method in model_mixin, which is included in your app's model)

Has someone had a situation like this before? Any ways out? At least a 'reliable' way to create and overwrite some methods in the engine's classes and to call them inside a mixin?

Comment: Ok, just after sending the question I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964050/rails-engines-extending-functionality. I didn't think it would help a lot before, as it is about extending from the main app. But after reading it again, this seems to work: `require Alchemy::Engine.root.join('app', 'models', 'alchemy', 'element')

  class Alchemy::Element
   def self.mymethod
    'anything'
   end
  end` Can anyone confirm that this is a good idea?

Comment: Ok, not a good idea... It works fine if the class has no dependencies,  otherwise they of course has to be required, too. Doesn't seem to be the best way, though...

Comment: I know this a while later .. but what did you end up doing to get the problem solved? Did you try out using polymorphic relationships to get this accomplished by any chance ?

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to monkey-patch the Alchemy::Page model in the following fashion:

```rb
require File.expand_path('../../app/models/alchemy/page', Alchemy::Engine.called_from)

module Alchemy

  class Page < BaseRecord

    # Your code goes here...

  end
end
```

Note the **require** statement which will ensure that the original class is extended and not overwritten by your file.

See [this blog post for more context](https://dockyard.com/blog/ruby/2012/02/20/rails-engines-and-monkey-patching).